# How to exclude the date format from the list in C#

Tags: c#, date-formatting, c#-8.0

I want to return the valid dates from the input and convert them into a specific format like yyyyMMdd. I want to return only valid date formats

```
public static List<string> TransformDateFormat(List<string> dates)
{
         
        var formats = new string[]
        {
            "yyyy/MM/dd",
            "dd/MM/yyyy",
            "MM-dd-yyyy",
            "dd.MM.yyyy"      
    };          
        return dates
            .Select(date => DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, null).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
            .ToList();     
}
```

Comment: Use `TryParseExact`, and it would be easier without LINQ.

Comment: @Llama tried but didn't work with that as well.

Comment: Can you calrify what you mean by "it didn't work"? If `TryParseExact` returns `false` then it was unable to parse the value, so you shouldn't include it in your list. Otheriwse, you can include the resulting value in the list. I don't understand how it wouldn't work?

Comment: @TomasTomov is returning an invalid date as well. "20130720" this date should be removed from the list and when I remove the format from the list it throws an exception like "NotImplementaiton exception"

Comment: Why should it be removed? You have explicitly declared that that is a format you accept.

Comment: Please be explicit: what are you trying to do here? What is the issue you're facing here? Can you elaborate on what was wrong with `TryParseExact`?

Comment: @Llama Sorry, I have modified the code, please take a look now. It has to be compared and check if the valid date it has to convert and return into yyyyMMdd format if it's not a valid format it shouldn't be in the list

Comment: @Tim OP had yyyyMMdd in their format list, but they want to reject those dates.

Comment: This question again, why did you delete the one from yesterday and make a new one?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` which takes an array of valid formats:

```
private static readonly string[] validFormats = {"yyyy/MM/dd","dd/MM/yyyy","MM-dd-yyyy"};

public static IEnumerable<string> TransformDateFormat(IEnumerable<string> dates)
{
        return dates
            .Where(date => DateTime.TryParseExact(date, validFormats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt));
}
```

---

```
var input = new List<string> { "2010/02/20", "19/12/2016", "11-18-2012", "20130720" };
List<string> result = TransformDateFormat(input).ToList();
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,result));
```

You should also add a parameter for the `IFormatProvider` parameter. I have used `null` which means "current culture". You can pass any culture there.

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/80TjPt)

If you want to transform it to a new format you can use this code:

```
private static readonly string[] validFormats = {"yyyy/MM/dd","dd/MM/yyyy","MM-dd-yyyy" };
private static readonly string targetFormat = "yyyyMMdd";

public static IEnumerable<string> TransformDateFormat(IEnumerable<string> dates)
{
        return dates
            .Select(date => DateTime.TryParseExact(date, validFormats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt) ? dt : new DateTime?())
            .Where(date => date.HasValue)
            .Select(date => date.Value.ToString(targetFormat));
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K98duH)

Comment: Good luck, I gave this exact solution yesterday and OP said it was wrong as well. Its not clear what the op is asking.

Comment: @zaggler And now OP has accepted it. How bizarre.

Comment: @Llama: Nope, unaccepted :D However, i have now edited it since i think that i've understood his requirement now.

Comment: OP _had_ accepted it. But apparently unaccepted it. It would be nice if OP could clarify exactly what they want if neither of our answers are an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParseExact`. I'll provide this as an answer here in the hopes that it works around whatever issue you had when you tried it yourself.

```
List<string> reformattedDates = new List<string>();
foreach (string date in dates)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime parsedDate))
    {
        reformattedDates.Add(parsedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    }
}
return reformattedDates;
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/SJDAGD93438)

By the way, the sample in the question seems to return dates in their original formats, whereas your code returns them in yyyyMMdd format. If you actually want to return them in their original formats, you should use [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67918945/3181933).